# $G_1 \rtimes G_2 \cong G_3 \implies BG_1 \times BG_2 \simeq BG_3$? $G_1 \times G_2 \cong G_3 \implies BG_1 \times BG_2 \simeq BG_3$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

As summarized in the title, suppose there is an isomorphism between $G_1 \times G_2$ and $G_3$, is it always true that $BG_1 \times BG_2$ is homotopy equivalent to $BG_3$?  If it is not always true could you give a counterexample and the condition for it to be true?

Similarly suppose there is an isomorphism between $G_1 \rtimes G_2$ and $G_3$, is it always true that $BG_1 \times BG_2$ is homotopy equivalent to $BG_3$?  If it is not always true could you give a counterexample and the condition for it to be true?

Comment: In your title you have a semi-direct product.  At this level of generality the conclusion is false.  Your question is more appropriate for MSE.  To make the conclusion true you would need to turn the product on the right-hand side into a fibration.

Comment: @RyanBudney: how to request migrating to MSE then?

Comment: Two groups $G, H$ are isomorphic iff $BG$ and $BH$ are homotopy equivalent. So the answer to the first question is yes and the answer to the second question is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_{G_i}:EG_i\rightarrow BG_i$ be the universal fibration, $i=1,2$, then
$p_{G_1}\times p_{G_2}:EG_1 \times EG_2 \rightarrow BG_1\times BG_2$ is the universal fibration of $G_1\times G_2$ since it is a $G_1\times G_2$ principal bundle and $EG_1\times EG_2$ is contractible, thus $BG_1\times BG_2=B(G_1\times G_2)$.

if you consider the semi-direct product $H$ of $G_1$ and $G_2$, since $G_1$ is a subgroup of $H$, the quotient $EH/G_1$ is a classifying space of $G_1$. There is   a section $s:G_2\rightarrow H$, remark that $G_2$ acts on $EH/G_1$ via this section since $g_2g_1x=g_2g_1g_2^{-1}g_2x$, thus if $x=g_1x, g_1\in G_1$, $g_2(g_1x)=g'_1g_2x$ since $G_1$ is a normal subgroup, $(EH/G_1)/G_2=B(G_1\times G_2)$ you have a fibration $EH/G_1 = BG_1\rightarrow B(G_1\times G_2)$.